# Safe to assume same order in index as store with upper part of key same?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

So I've got a store in indexeddb with a composed keyPath: `[someKey, someSubKey]`. I've got an index on `someKey`. I am looking for the fastest way to delete all object for a given `someKey`. The approach I'm trying to go with is to get the lower and upper subkey on the index, and then delete on the store with a key range between lower and upper subkey.

This works, at least in Firefox and Chrome. But it assumes the order of values will be the same in the index as in the store. I'm wondering if this is a safe assumption to make? I'm thinking it might, as the key paths of store and index share the first key, but can't find much documentation on sorting order. I'd rather not delete every record individually as there could be thousands of them.

The psuedo-code below describes the approach:

```
const someKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(givenSomeKey);
const lowerSubKey = index.openKeyCursor(someKeyRange, "next")
  .primaryKey[1];
const upperSubKey = index.openKeyCursor(someKeyRange, "prev")
  .primaryKey[1]; //1 to get subKey
const storeRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(
  [givenSomeKey, lowerSubKey],
  [givenSomeKey, upperSubKey]
);
store.delete(storeRange);
```

Comment: Last i checked you cannot delete a range of keys, only one key at a time. Also, there is IDBIndex.prototype.delete, no need to use IDBObjectStore.prototype.delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key ordering is defined here:

https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct

Specifically for your case, with array keys, they are member-wise ordered. i.e. if `A` < `B`, then `[A, ...]` < `[B, ...]`.

And yes, if you were to delete the range `IDBKeyRange.bound([A], [B], false, true)` that would delete anything with `[A, ...]`. (This assumes there is no value between A and B. Sadly, there's no prefix-range in the API. https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/47)